# Mathematica equations to LaTeX but equation is too long, how to split it?

Tags: equations, wolfram-mathematica

I am new user of LaTeX. I have a problem of splitting long equation which I generate by Mathematica. I tried to use `\\`, `multiline`, and `split` commands but it gives error. Is there way to export equation from Mathematica written in `multiline` because the equation is too long?

My equation is

```
\[\left(\text{xg} \text{Cos}\left[\alpha _2+\theta _1\right]+(g+\text{yg}) \text{Sin}\left[\alpha _2+\theta _1\right]\right) m_2 R_2+\left(\text{Cos}\left[\alpha
_c+\theta _1\right] \text{Cos}\left[\theta _1+\omega _c\right] d_c k_d+\left(\text{xg} \text{Cos}\left[\alpha _c+\theta _1\right]+(g+\text{yg}) \text{Sin}\left[\alpha
_c+\theta _1\right]\right) m_d-\text{Cos}\left[\alpha _c+\theta _1\right] \text{Sin}\left[\alpha _1\right] k_d R_1\right) R_c<\left(d \text{Cos}\left[\omega
-\alpha _2\right] m_2 R_2+\text{Cos}\left[\alpha _c-\omega _c\right] d_c m_d R_c\right) \left(\theta _1'\right){}^2+\left(\text{IG2}+d \text{Sin}\left[\omega
-\alpha _2\right] m_2 R_2-\text{Sin}\left[\alpha _c-\omega _c\right] d_c m_d R_c\right) \theta _1''\]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you extend that to an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), also including the version that does not work and your error message?

Comment: Could you post the Mathematica expression itself? i.e. in Mathematica own expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done the following with your equation:

- I've gotten rid of all `\left` and `\right` statements in favor of the following bracketing system: Innermost: square brackets, size default (small); next: round parentheses, size `\big`; outermost (just one instance): curly braces, size `\big`. The explicit sizing instructions are needed because the material enclosed in the `\left ... \right` pairs isn't big; hence the "fences" (brackets, parentheses, and braces) will all have the same minimum size *unless* explicit sizing instructions are provided.
- Using the `multline*` environment of the `amsmath` package, I've broken up the expression into four lines, placing the `<` symbol at the start of the third line.
- Replaced all `\text{Sin}` and `\text{Cos}` instances with `\sin` and `\cos`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry} %choose margins for your document
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\bigl(\text{xg} \cos[\alpha_2+\theta_1]
+(g+\text{yg}) \sin[\alpha_2+\theta_1]\bigr) m_2 R_2
+\bigl\{\cos[\alpha_c+\theta_1] \cos[\theta_1+\omega_c] d_c k_d\\
+\bigl(\text{xg} \cos[\alpha_c+\theta_1]
+(g+\text{yg}) \sin[\alpha_c+\theta_1]\bigr) m_d
-\cos[\alpha_c+\theta_1] \sin[\alpha_1] k_d R_1\bigr\} R_c\\
<\bigl(d \cos[\omega -\alpha_2] m_2 R_2
+\cos[\alpha_c-\omega_c] d_c m_d R_c\bigr)(\theta_1')^2\\
+\bigl(\text{IG2}+d \sin[\omega -\alpha_2] m_2 R_2
-\sin[\alpha_c-\omega_c] d_c m_d R_c\bigr) \theta_1''
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @egreg has remarked in a comment, it's more common to use round parentheses as the innermost fences, square brackets for the mid-rank fences, and curly braces for the outermost fences. Switching the order of parentheses and brackets in the preceding examples produces the following look:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry} %choose margins for your document
\usepackage{amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\bigl[\text{xg} \cos(\alpha_2+\theta_1)
+(g+\text{yg}) \sin(\alpha_2+\theta_1)\bigl] m_2 R_2
+\bigl\{\cos(\alpha_c+\theta_1) \cos(\theta_1+\omega_c) d_c k_d\\
+\bigl[\text{xg} \cos(\alpha_c+\theta_1)
+(g+\text{yg}) \sin(\alpha_c+\theta_1)\bigl] m_d
-\cos(\alpha_c+\theta_1) \sin(\alpha_1) k_d R_1\bigr\} R_c\\
<\bigl[d \cos(\omega -\alpha_2) m_2 R_2
+\cos(\alpha_c-\omega_c) d_c m_d R_c\bigl](\theta_1')^2\\
+\bigl[\text{IG2}+d \sin(\omega -\alpha_2) m_2 R_2
-\sin(\alpha_c-\omega_c) d_c m_d R_c\bigl] \theta_1''
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually `[]` mark the external group; it's quite funny to see `sin[x+y]`

Comment: That might be (cf. OP post) due to Mathematica, where functions have their arguments in `[]` and are written with a capital letter, e.g. `Cos[a]` calls cosine in Mathematica.

Comment: @egreg -- I've provided an addendum to the answer, in which I switch the order of round parentheses and square brackets (while keeping curly braces to denote the outermost group). The result is indeed quite a bit easier on the eye!

Comment: I'd appreciate to all for improvement in the equation. However I would like to know weather there is any command which directly transfer Mathematica code into LaTex considering all the improvement done above???

Comment: @SanjeevPrajapati - Thanks! I'm afraid I don't use Mathematica in my own work and hence don't know how to answer your follow-up question. Nor is your follow-up question -- which, by the way, is a very good one! -- going to be seen much if it's posted as a comment to an existing answer. May I suggest you post a separate, new question that asks for hints on how one might program Mathematic so that it generates more-appealing LaTeX code?

Answer (score 11):

this uses `multline` (not `multiline`), and changes one pair of parentheses that would have
to be split between lines to `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.

as harish kumar points out, this should use `\sin` and `\cos` rather than `\text`, but i didn't change those.  also, `\mathrm` would be better than `\text` for "`xg`" and similar, since `\text` follows the surrounding text style, which would be italic in a theorem environment.  (i didn't change those either.)

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\left(\text{xg} \text{Cos}\left[\alpha _2+\theta _1\right]+(g+\text{yg})
  \text{Sin}\left[\alpha _2+\theta _1\right]\right) m_2 R_2\\
+\bigl(\text{Cos}\left[\alpha_c+\theta _1\right]
  \text{Cos}\left[\theta _1+\omega_c\right] d_c k_d\\
+\left(\text{xg} \text{Cos}\left[\alpha _c+\theta _1\right]+(g+\text{yg})
  \text{Sin}\left[\alpha_c+\theta _1\right]\right) m_d\\
-\text{Cos}\left[\alpha _c+\theta _1\right]
  \text{Sin}\left[\alpha _1\right] k_d R_1\bigr)R_c\\
<\left(d \text{Cos}\left[\omega-\alpha_2\right] m_2 R_2
  +\text{Cos}\left[\alpha _c-\omega _c\right] d_c m_d R_c\right)
  \left(\theta _1'\right){}^2\\
+\left(\text{IG2}+d \text{Sin}\left[\omega-\alpha _2\right] m_2 R_2
 -\text{Sin}\left[\alpha _c-\omega _c\right] d_c m_d R_c\right) \theta _1''
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I removed all `\left` and `\right` as they seem to be un-necessary. Also, `\text{Cos}` and `\text{Sin}` looked odd to me and I changed. Further, many parenthesis and brackets may be reduced to make the equation less cluttered (this is an assignment left)

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
  &(\text{xg} \cos[\alpha _2+\theta _1]+(g+\text{yg}) \sin[\alpha _2+\theta _1]) m_2 R_2
  +(\cos[\alpha_c+\theta _1] \cos[\theta _1+\omega _c] d_c k_d\\
  &\quad +(\text{xg} \cos[\alpha _c+\theta _1]+(g+\text{yg}) \sin[\alpha
_c+\theta _1]) m_d-\cos[\alpha _c+\theta _1] \sin[\alpha _1] k_d R_1) R_c\\
&\quad <(d \cos[\omega-\alpha _2] m_2 R_2+\cos[\alpha _c-\omega _c] d_c m_d R_c) (\theta _1'){}^2\\
&\qquad + (\text{IG2}+d \sin[\omega-\alpha _2] m_2 R_2-\sin[\alpha _c-\omega _c] d_c m_d R_c) \theta _1''
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to move the `+` symbol from the end of the third line to the start of the final line -- and indent the final line by, say, `\qquad` instead of just `\quad`. It may also be a good idea to provide some fence-sizing instructions by hand to help guide the reader's eye; you are right, though, in that the `\left` and `\right` directives aren't doing anything useful since don't increase the sizes of the associated fences for the equation at hand.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I made some changes. The parenthesis adjustment, as I told in answer, is a home work for the OP :)

Answer (score 5):

I find that if things are aligned that they are easier to read, especially for the case where there is significant repetition:

[image]

### Notes:

- I defined macros for `\xg`, `\yg` and `\IG` with `\mathrm` as per @barbara beeton's suggestion. However as they are macros they are easier to change.
- To get proper alignment of the `\cos` and `\sin`, I define macros to do account for the case that the `\cos` is slightly wider than the `\sin`.  Unfortunately, this still necessitated an additional tweak of `\,`, but I am not sure exactly why that was necessary.
- The `\Sub` macro to to take into account the fact that the subscript `2` is slightly wider than the subscript `c`.
- Several `\hphantom`s were used to align things.  Could use `alignat*` environment as well but that would also require the use of `\lap` family of macros.
- The square braces, `[]`, have been moved to the exterior with round parenthesis, `()`, used for internal grouping. Also, a `\Big[`, `\Big]` was used to clearly identify the grouping that is across two lines.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\xg}{\mathrm{xg}}%
\newcommand{\yg}{\mathrm{yg}}%
\newcommand{\IG}{\mathrm{IG2}}%
\newcommand{\Sin}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\cos (#1)$}][r]{$\sin (#1)$}}%
\newcommand{\Sub}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\scriptstyle2$}][l]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
  &\big[ \xg \cos(\alpha _2+\theta _1)+(g+\yg) \sin(\alpha _2+\theta _1) \big] m_2 R_2 
      +\Big[\cos(\alpha_c +\theta _1) \cos(\theta _1+\omega _c) d_c k_d\\
  {}+{}&\big[ \xg \cos(\alpha_{\Sub{c}}+\theta _1)+(g+\yg) \sin(\alpha_c+\theta _1) \big] m_d \hphantom{R_2}
      -\hphantom{\Big(}\cos(\alpha _c+\theta _1) \sin(\alpha _1 \hphantom{{}+\omega _c}) k_d R_1\Big] R_c\\
&\quad <\hphantom{{}+{}} \big[ \hphantom{\IG+{}} d \cos(\omega-\alpha _2) m_2 R_2 + \cos(\alpha_c-\omega _c) d_c m_d R_c \big] (\theta _1'){}^2\\
&\quad \hphantom{{}<{}} + \big[\IG + d \,\Sin{\omega-\alpha _2} m_2 R_2 - \Sin{\alpha_c-\omega _c} d_c m_d R_c \big] \hphantom{(} \theta _1''
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\hphantom{{}<} (\mathrm{xg}\cos[\alpha_{2} + \theta_{1}] + (g + \mathrm{yg})\sin[\alpha_{2} + \theta_{1}]) m_{2} R_{2}\\
  &\hphantom{{}<} + (\cos[\alpha_{c} + \theta_{1}] \cos[\theta_{1} + \omega_{c}] d_{c} k_{d}\\
  &\hphantom{{}< + (} + (\mathrm{xg}\cos[\alpha_{c} + \theta_{1}] + (g + \mathrm{yg})\sin[\alpha_{c} + \theta_{1}]) m_{d}\\
  &\hphantom{{}< + (} - \cos[\alpha_{c} + \theta_{1}] \sin[\alpha_{1}] k_{d} R_{1}) R_{c}\\
  &< (d \cos[\omega - \alpha_{2}] m_{2} R_{2} + \cos[\alpha_{c} - \omega_{c}] d_{c} m_{d} R_{c}) (\theta_{1}')^{2}\\
  &\hphantom{{}<} + (\mathrm{IG2} + d \sin[\omega - \alpha_{2}] m_{2} R_{2} - \sin[\alpha_{c} - \omega_{c}] d_{c} m_{d} R_{c}) \theta_{1}''
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that sine and cosine are mathematical operators, so they should be typeset using `\sin` and `\cos`.